# How to create Custom Activity Feed (website oriented) in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-fql

My client want's a facebook activity feed on their site (this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/, the kind that shows activity related to the site, most commonly likes and shares from the site). Inserting it is fine, but I'm hell bent on customizing the appearance to blend in with the site as per the client's wishes. My original plan to just use jQuery to strip out the stylesheets in the iframe and insert my own doesn't seem to be possible, so I imagine it would be possible to just use FQL or the Graph API to fetch the feed myself in PHP and print it out. However, I can't for the life of me find any documentation on getting activity related to a domain/url. Largely I just need to know how to fetch the data, I can figure out how to process it from there.

To restate, I'm essentially recreating this: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?site=http://applereviews.com on my own server. Maybe not the ajax updating but at least fetching the feed on page load.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a Fan Page you have to get 'manage my pages' access authority on an administrator's personal account for the Fan Page by using a Facebook App as a pass-through.  Basically the administrator of the Fan Page has to install & grant access rights to the Facebook App.

```
$userInfo = $facebook->api("/".$pageAdminId);

if(isset($userInfo)):
 global $appId, $appSecret;

 $accessToken = $this->get_content("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_
    token?type=client_cred&client_id=".$appId."&client_secret=".$appSecret);
$accessToken = substr($accessToken, strpos($accessToken, "=") + 1);
```

Once you do that, you can use the access token granted by the page administrator to hit

`https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_fan_page_id/feed?access_token=$accessToken`

and get anything you'd like.  Just remember to request up to and including 'manage my pages' authority or the token won't allow you the properly data-level access.